# Clean install Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 from OEM key

Tags: windows-8, installation, windows-8.1, licensing

I have recently acquired a laptop with an OEM Windows 8 product key.  I am interested in a **clean install** of Windows 8.1.  I do not have any original install media, only recovery disks, and the recovery disks perform a pre-programmed install which does not have the correct partition scheme that I need, and also install lots of programs that I do not want.

The common way to clean install Windows 8.1 with a Windows 8 key shown on websites is to use Microsoft's upgrade site to download the install media by starting the Windows 8 download first, pausing it, then starting the Windows 8.1 download.  My Windows 8 OEM key is rejected with the message `This product key cannot be used to install a retail version of Windows 8`.  I have tried using the generic keys provided in numerous threads, but these are all rejected with the message `We can't connect right now` (research shows that this is due to a key problem and not a network problem, I have confirmed the network is fine.)

If I was to obtain the 8.1 install media, am I right in thinking that I could install using the dummy key and later legitimately activate with my Win8 OEM key?  If not, could I do the equivalent for Windows 8 install media?  A clean Win8 upgraded through to 8.1 is still preferable to the wrongly-partitioned OEM version.

Is this even possible?  If it's not possible, are the manufacturer under obligation to provide me with "clean" install disks on request?

Comment: What you want is possible.  Get the Windows 8.1 installation the. Follow the directions to the answer in this very website to that question ( it's one of my answers )

Comment: The OEM key only works for Windows 8 DVDs, NOT for 8.1. To reinsatll 8.1, install 8.0 from a clean MSDN/Technet ISO and update with the Store to 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound confirmed working.  The generic key `XHQ8N-C3MCJ-RQXB6-WCHYG-C9WKB` works with the 8.1 Pro RTM install DVD with SHA1 sum `42458E48CECEBAB8BF5D58220478FDA42B0D2990`.  A valid OEM key (non retail!) **was** accepted for 8.1 activation after installation, contrary to what lots of people have said.  However it looks to be *impossible* to obtain the ISO directly from MS with an OEM key and without an MSDN subscription.  Wouldn't care to comment on whether obtaining it elsewhere is legal or not but it's surely moral.

Comment: @amoe - Your OEM can provide you the required installation media.

Comment: @Ramhound except that is like getting blood from a stone with most OEMs

Answer (score 55):

I have successfully been able to swap licenses by first installing a retail version. At the end of this article you will *also* find [a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He9wg7pqHPI) on how to do all of this if you do not want to read all of the below.

## PRETEXT

Windows 8 OEM machines no longer include a COA sticker or label at the bottom of your laptop with your serial number. If you need to re-install your Windows and your hard drive's recovery cannot be accessed or you forget to create recovery discs - it's a difficult process.

Here are the reasons people want to clean install Windows 8.1:

1. Some people believe a clean install is better than an upgrade from Windows 8
2. People forget to do a recovery disc backup and their hard drive's recovery doesn't work. This could be for a variety of reasons (mine was a new SSD installation, while others have reported wiping their drives or recovery partitions becoming inactive or corrupt)
3. Guaranteed removal of bloatware—even if you did obtain recovery discs, people don't like all the added on applications that OEMs supply with their machines.
4. Saving the $$$ involved in obtaining recovery discs from the manufacturer (such as Toshiba who thought it was ok to charge me $68 US to ship me recovery discs—with bloatware)

---

## Here is the process

First, find yourself a retail copy of Windows 8.1 ISO. Get the version that corresponds with what came with your laptop (e.g. Professional 64bit). You can download from [My Digital Life forums](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/59229-Windows-8-1-x86-x64-ISO-Download-ALL-VERSION-LANG-HTTP-links) or even find one as a torrent or download directly from Microsoft if you happen to also have a valid retail serial number or dev account. (Remember, downloading a Microsoft ISO is NOT illegal as long as you are installing it with a legal license)

**I recommend to check the SHA-1 hash** to make sure the ISO files are original if downloading from torrents, else you may end up with a tampered OS with backdoors which will be nearly impossible to remove (implementing backdoors on a OS install disc allows to bypass any security measure of the OS and thus make them completely undetectable). You can check the official SHA-1 hashes directly from [Microsoft's MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/?#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=545&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0), then just click on Details on the entry that corresponds to the ISO you downloaded to show the hash.

Next, install the ISO by burning it to a DVD and booting from the DVD. You may have to change your BIOS settings to allow booting from DVD as the first boot device.

Install Windows 8.1 Retail with a generic key. Microsoft has now released LEGAL generic keys used for the sole purpose of installing Windows 8.1 as an INACTIVATED copy.

Generic keys can be found by simply googling:

`windows 8.1 [version] [32 or 64 bit] generic key`

Finally, once the Windows installation finishes, open up an elevated command prompt. To do this right click on the Windows button and click **Command Prompt (Admin)**.

In the window type: `slmgr /upk`

This will uninstall the product key (which is generic and inactivated anyway).

Once this is done, use a program like [**RW Everything**](http://rweverything.com/) to extract the key that is embedded in the bios of your OEM machine. Once you open it, click on the ACPI button then click the MSDM tab. Your key will appear at the end of the data window as the value for the key "Data".

Open an elevated command prompt again and type: `slui 3`

This will open up a GUI request for your product key. Paste the key from **RW Everything**.

That's it, you're all done.

You will notice you are fully activated and all of your Windows updates will work.

I have *also* made [a simple tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He9wg7pqHPI) that explains how to do it all for those that want a more visual demonstration.

Comment: www.hecticated.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed

Comment: Here's the YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He9wg7pqHPI

Comment: Best answer to the problem on the Internet.

Comment: "I recommend to check the MD5 hash to make sure the files are original if downloading from torrents." => Can you expand on this? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeCole I have edited the answer, the edit should appear soon. You can check the SHA1 hash from [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/?#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=545&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) directly, and it is quite advised as a tampered OS can contain backdoors that will be completely undetectable once the OS gets installed on a computer (the backdoors can be placed above the OS itself, so the OS won't even be able to access the backdoors in any way).

Comment: There is now an official Microsoft tool to make the installation media. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Comment: Where at My Digital Life forums is the ISO supposed to be found? Perhaps you could link directly, instead of just to the forum's home page.

Comment: Does it mean that if I replace Win8.1 with Ubuntu and after some time decide to install Win8.1 back, I'll still be able to use the key from UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: This does not work. Windows won't take the OEM key.

Answer (score 10):

simple fix is to get the windows 8.1 or windows 8 iso 
then make \sources\ei.cfg and put

```
[EditionID]
[Channel]
OEM
[VL]
0
```

into it and save the iso as bootable or just copy everything to a usbstick

Comment: Would be cool if anyone could confirm this

Comment: you can test it your self in a virtualbox or something :)

Comment: Found the reference here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824952.aspx

Comment: does this work with the retail ISO image?

Comment: try change "OEM" with "Retail" and it should work, but do try in Virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, then Microsoft allows customers with OEM installations to download [Refresh Media](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) from their site since November 2014 (source: [article](http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Microsoft-stellt-Download-fuer-ISO-von-Windows-8-1-bereit-2454287.html) on Heise.de in german, but [ars technica](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/02/save-yourself-from-your-oems-bad-decisions-with-a-clean-install-of-windows-8-1/) is good as well). I recall that there was also a campaign advertising a bloatware-free Windows 8 installation around that time, but I cannot find any sources or remember a particular keyword.

Microsoft also offers [Refresh Media for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) since day one.

Note that the site will offer you an ISO if it detects a browser [User-Agent](https://superuser.com/q/445869/252532) indicating a non-Windows operating system. Also note that while you should backup contents on the USB drive you want to use, you don't have to format it if you intend to install with UEFI. If you have enough free space, just create a new folder and put everything that is already on the drive temporarily in there and [follow the first part of this guide](https://askubuntu.com/q/395879/40581). (7z works the same way on Windows, just replace the name of the Ubuntu ISO with Windows and copy files.) Ideally it saves you a bit of time, writes to flash cells and may be saves you the hassle of finding a free USB drive. After the installation is done you just move the content from the temporary folder back the where it was.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you understand the issue: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/a-clean-install-of-windows-8-oem-media-download/1b1e2517-5658-450d-943e-7e81f902adec?page=2

The problem is that Microsoft allows OEM vendors to change the installation medium. Companies like HP and Dell usually install a lot of crap on it with trials for e.g. McAfee antivirus, Office trial products and so forth. They do this because they make extra money off of it.

The only option I can really think of. I've had to deal with problems like this many many times and Dell is really unwilling to provide a clean installation medium. Maybe if you have orders of several millions or so, they're willing to do an extra effort, but for the normal people, it's what you have to live with.

You could try and see if you can download a clean OEM version somewhere on the internet and see if your serial works on it. I know you can torrent the necessary iso files but I have my questions about the legality of it all...
If you don't like the junk that comes with OEM versions, you should buy a retail version. It is much more expensive, but easier to deal with + you are allowed to install it on different hardware too.