# How to clean (re)install of Windows 8 OEM to a new SSD?

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, oem

I know this was asked many times, however I have not found an exact answer or method suitable for Asus. (closest question, but no clear answer: [Clean install Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 from OEM key](https://superuser.com/questions/697253/clean-install-windows-8-1-or-windows-8-from-oem-key))

I just got a new Asus N550JK and it came with big HDD and Windows 8.1 OEM. I have an 100gb SSD from previous laptop and I want to use Windows that came with Asus laptop. How to correctly clean install on SSD the OEM windows?

## Desired path

1. I get the serial number with some software like belarc.
2. Get windows 8.1 installer with serial (i would use [cd-key and official download](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only))
3. Do clean install and loose some OEM software (not even sure)

Should this work, or OEM windows does not go that easy?

## Other options

What would be other options (recommended)?

- Create OEM recovery media or iso (considering that ASUS does not have an official software)
- Clone directly to SSD with software

Well I dont know any other options. Asus came with a lot of preinstalled software, but I am sure I can get some of them on my laptop model driver page, but i really dont care about them. I just want a clean and fast os on my SSD.

(also i will be using optical bay caddy to use both SSD & HDD). Help, tips, tutorials are very appreciated. Just want to make this right! Thanks community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 for consumer devices such as your laptop does not use a serial number printed on a sticker any more. Instead the serial number is stored internally in the laptop and Windows 8 will pick it up automatically.

To re-install you simply need a Windows 8 OEM disc. The install process will pick up your laptop's key, select the correct version of Windows to install and activate online for you automatically.

Comment: I understand that, as I mentioned I can check up my serial number with software. I dont have OEM disc and surely I dont want to buy it.

Comment: You can't install an OEM copy the way you want to. The key won't work with anything other than an OEM copy of Windows. You will need to obtain an OEM disc.

Comment: Look for an ISO with the SHA1 hash 1F18420D65956DFE56E2359DA71AB6C363146570. That is the one you need and should be easy to download.