# Windows 8.1 Re-Installation on Acer Aspire - Key Issue

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, uefi, acer-aspire

On Acer Aspire V3 model, Windows 8 recovery partition could not complete a fresh installation. It kept stumbling on error; it seems corrupted though I check the disk for erros/bad sectors and did not find any. Acer support also didn't help and said the laptop is out of warranty. And with these new laptops, Windows key is embedded in the UEFI.

So I followed the instruction on this:
[Clean install Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 from OEM key](https://superuser.com/questions/697253/clean-install-windows-8-1-or-windows-8-from-oem-key)

And used the Windows installation media maker from windows website and gave it a generic key. So I did a clean Windows 8.1 installation (trial with the generic key).

But Windows 8.1 did NOT accept my key that I recovered from UEFI using rw-everything. Is there something I did wrong? I tried to match the Windows installation media to what was previous installed on the laptop.

I bought a laptop with an OS on it and now I lost it. I am lost between Microsoft and Acer.

Comment: Let's get more specific information, for instance, what version exaxtly did you have installed previously?  You used the new tool to download the ISO correct?

Comment: What might be easier is to install Windows 8.0 then update that to 8.1 less things to go wrong and you skip having to use a generic key.

Comment: UEFI key alone will not work or the pirates would have a hay day, it more than just the key required these days, there are also certificates installed. Also a UEFI key is not the same as an OEM key.